# STM32F407 SPI While Reading Datas of LIS3DSH

Tags: spi

```
 uint8_t SPI_Rx(uint8_t address)
    {
     GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOE,GPIO_Pin_3);
     address    =   (0x80) | (address);
        
     while(!SPI_I2S_GetFlagStatus(SPI1,SPI_FLAG_TXE));     
     SPI_I2S_SendData(SPI1,address);
     while(!SPI_I2S_GetFlagStatus(SPI1,SPI_FLAG_RXNE));
     SPI_I2S_ReceiveData(SPI1);
        
     while(!SPI_I2S_GetFlagStatus(SPI1,SPI_FLAG_TXE));     
     SPI_I2S_SendData(SPI1,0x00);
     while(!SPI_I2S_GetFlagStatus(SPI1,SPI_FLAG_RXNE));
     SPI_I2S_ReceiveData(SPI1);
        
     GPIO_SetBits(GPIOE,GPIO_Pin_3);
     return SPI_I2S_ReceiveData(SPI1);
```

Hi, what you see is SPI reading functions for LIS3DSH sensor. First of all, After I send adress knowledge, SPI RX buffer receives datas of LIS3DSH sensor. But then why does it need to receive data of LIS3DSH sensor by sending "0x00" ? Briefly, why do we need to send else data again while we already received datas? Ahead of time ,Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When reading data from a register of the LIS3DSH, the entire SPI transaction is two bytes long:

- Byte 1: The master sends the register address (incl. a read/write flag) to the sensor.
- Byte 2: The sensor sends the register value to the master.

However, SPI is a full-duplex protocol. For each bit and byte, both the master and the slave (sensor) send data. So the real communication in fact looks like so:

- Byte 1

  - Master sends register address.
  - Slave sends 0 or any random value.
- Byte 2

  - Master sends 0.
  - Slave sends register value.

This is what you see in the code:

```
 while(!SPI_I2S_GetFlagStatus(SPI1,SPI_FLAG_TXE));  // Wait for SPI bus to be ready
 SPI_I2S_SendData(SPI1,address);                    // Submit byte 1 to be sent
 while(!SPI_I2S_GetFlagStatus(SPI1,SPI_FLAG_RXNE)); // Wait for byte 1 from slave
 SPI_I2S_ReceiveData(SPI1);                         // Retrieve byte 1 from slave and ignore it
    
 while(!SPI_I2S_GetFlagStatus(SPI1,SPI_FLAG_TXE));  // Wait for SPI bus to be ready
 SPI_I2S_SendData(SPI1,0x00);                       // Send 0 as byte 2
 while(!SPI_I2S_GetFlagStatus(SPI1,SPI_FLAG_RXNE)); // Wait for byte 2 from slave
 SPI_I2S_ReceiveData(SPI1);                         // Retrieve byte 2 and ??

 GPIO_SetBits(GPIOE,GPIO_Pin_3);                    // Deassert CS?
 return SPI_I2S_ReceiveData(SPI1);                  // Retrieve byte 2 again and return it
```

The last part is somewhat strange. `SPI_I2S_ReceiveData()` is called twice at the end probably assuming that it will return the same value twice. It would probably be cleaner if it was called only once.

Comment: Thank you. I got it. Your post is really clear.